# Flutter GetX controller not dispose on bottom sheet

Tags: flutter, bottom-sheet, flutter-getx

Hi I am creating a bottom sheet as stateless widget and I am using a GetXController,

if I use Get.bottomsheet to create bottom sheet, controller is getting release while I dismiss the sheet which is correct but I am not able to increase the height of bottom sheet.

if I use flutter inbuilt showModalBottomSheet to create bottom sheet, I am able to increase the height of bottom Sheet but controller is not releasing while I dismiss, below is the code,

I need to increase the bottom sheet height as well release the controller on dismissing bottom sheet .

```
Class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {

   return TextButton(onPressed: () {
       
     // if we use like this on dismissing homepage, controller is also releasing, the problem of using this not able to adjust the height of bottom sheet using get
     Get.bottomSheet(HomePage());

   // if we use like this on dismissing homepage, controller is not releasing, by this approach we can control the height of bottom sheet but controller is not releasing  

    showModalBottomSheet(
     context: context,
     builder: (context) => HomePage(),
     enableDrag: false,
    );  
 });
  }

class GetC extends GetxController { }

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {   @override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final GetC controller = Get.put(GetC());
    return Text("Controller not releasing");   } }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Get.bottomsheet this way to set height according to your needs:

```
Get.bottomSheet(
      isScrollControlled: true,
      Container(
        height: 600, //specify your height here
        child: HomePage(),
      ),
    );
```

You can give the container height you want and it will open it with the height you provided in the Container height.